How to get out of a Windows recovery options loop?
Windows 11 Laptop goes to recovery options after failed Windows Update, can't boot into Windows.
Using the command prompt under the "advanced options" I can see that all my files in my C drive are still there and they're not corrupted. But it looks like the OS is, since the command bootrec/rebuildbcd cannot find a windows installation.
What can I do?

You will find several operations you can do in the article Windows 11/10 - Troubleshooting - Automatic Repair (Startup Repair) on Boot. Try them in order and see if one of them will solve the problem.

What you need to do are three things, first you need to restore the image using DISM. You have to have the wim file for a healthy image of windows 11 or installation source containing the same version of windows and then try and restore it.
https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/94173-how-use-dism-window-pe-environment.html
Then you would need to also run sfc /scannow in the recovery envirornment:
https://www.minitool.com/news/run-sfc-from-the-windows-recovery-environment.html
Then you would also need to restore the boot of the system:
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
bcdboot C:\windows
please first search online before performing these commands and how they apply to your case and situation, but generally this is the way to go restoring a failed update and a crashing windows image. Also please do note about the other options of the commands and how they can be used. And as a side note be mindful about the empty space.
Just do your research and then tell me how it turns out.
In case you have any questions please let me know.

the Wim file? What do you mean?

The first thing to do is to boot from rescue media and to make an image of the whole drive. It is possible that files will be lost during repair, and having a disk image allows them to be restored. There are many good tools for this, such as Macrium Rescue Environment, or those at MakeUseOf. Put the drive with the image side during repairs.
Likely, the easiest repair would be to download the Windows 11 ISO and put it on USB directly with the media creation tool. The perform reinstallation, as described by Microsoft, keeping your files. This is far more thorough than SFC/DISM repair, yet may take a shorter time, in some cases.
When the system is running well, restore from the image any files that were lost. It is also a very good idea, now that the PC is working correctly, to make another backup image, and to update that image periodically. Should an issue occur, even to hardware, such as a dead SSD, you can restore the entire image to new hardware, usually in less than half an hour.

The PC goes straight to recovery options, I have no way to image the system, because I can't go to the GUI.

to anyone still looking help for this. I managed to recover my data by attaching an external drive and copy/transfer the files there using CMD from the recovery options, I opened a notepad window and then called a mini Explorer GUI from there.
Now I'm just gonna proceed by normally reinstalling Win11 with a bootable USB, with all my data. (I hope it will work, but I think it will because I've done this a couple times before, I hope this time it won't be any different)
Anyway, thanks everyone for the help.
Of course, it'd have been better if I could have just fixed my current installation of Windows and kept using my PC without reinstalling, but nothing seems to work apparently, I think I've tried almost everything. But I'm still glad I recovered my data, it's enough for me.
note that my problem hasn't yet been resolved, so I think I will settle for reinstalling the OS in the end, but I'll keep researching for now and see if I can fix the problem completely without having to reinstall.
